# Android to ASP.NET error processing the request

Tags: c#, android, asp.net

When I send a request from Android to ASP.NET method there is an error:

> W/DefaultRequestDirector﹕ Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
>   W/MainActivity﹕ Error 401 for URL
>
> I/jsonResultStr :﹕ {"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

This is the ASP.NET method prototype:

```
public string GetBuildingData(string roadId)
```

This is the Android sendToAsp method:

```
public void sendToAsp() {
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://madenati.alameentech.com:8082/Coding/Services/BuildingsServices.asmx/GetBuildingData");
    httpPost.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpParameterObj(4000,4000));
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("roadId", "1");

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(data.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String jsonResultStr = reader.readLine();
        data = new JSONObject(jsonResultStr);
        final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " );
        }
        Log.i("jsonResultStr : ",jsonResultStr);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.v("Exception","Exception sendToAsp");

    }
}
```

This is getHttpParameterObj method:

```
private HttpParams getHttpParameterObj(int timeOutConnection,int timeOutSocket)
{
    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeOutConnection);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeOutSocket);
    return httpParameters;
}
```

and in Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: This may be error in your server side or recheck the input params you need to pass for accessing the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class to do request:

```
package com.alameen.mat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

public class WebService extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{

public String NameSpace = "";
public String MethodName = "";
SoapObject request;
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;
String URL="";
Activity context;
public WebService(Activity c, String nameSpace, String method, String url)
{
    context=c;
    NameSpace=nameSpace;
    MethodName=method;
    request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, MethodName);
    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    URL=url;
    androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,30000);
}

public void addProperty(String name,String val)
{
    request.addProperty(name,val);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    //Log.i("jsonArray from ASP.NET: ",result);
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();


}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(params[0], envelope);
        SoapObject  result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        String res = result.getProperty(0).toString();
        //Log.d("result", res);
        return  res;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        SoapFault fault = (SoapFault)envelope.bodyIn;
        Log.d("error", fault.getMessage()+"/"+fault.getCause());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
void log(String l)
{
    Log.d("status", l);
    }
}
```

call like this:

```
public static String URL="http://... .asmx?WSDL";
WebService ws = new WebService(This, "http://tempuri.org/", "methodName", URL);
```

and import this library to your project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5bi6yt8x5xpdbk/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar?dl=0